# How do I program a javascript function to switch button colors back and forth?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, onclick

I'm trying to turn a blue button red by using an onclick, but then I also want the button to turn back to being blue after clicking again using the same onclick function.

How would I do this?

Comment: What do you have so far? Provide some code, to see what the issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .round {
            border-radius: 5px;
            color: aliceblue;
        }
        .blue {
            background-color: blue;
        }
        .red {
            background-color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="btn" class="round blue" onclick="clickBtn()">button</button>
    <script>
        function clickBtn() {
            let btn = document.getElementById('btn')
            if(btn.classList.contains('blue')) {
                btn.classList.remove('blue')
                btn.classList.add('red')
            } else {
                btn.classList.remove('red')
                btn.classList.add('blue')
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `element.classList.add("mystyle");` would help if you're using more than one class. Then to remove it, `element.classList.remove("mystyle");` Instead if it "equaling" a class, use `element.classList.contains("mystyle");`

Comment: For example, if `<button class="blue round">` then className would be `"blue round"` and it would no longer match the if condition. It's more flexible to use the classList like @dgood says.

Comment: Yes.It's more flexible to use the classList.

Answer (score 1):

You can give the button a default background color, then add a `click` event listener to it which toggles a class that applies a different background color:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(){ this.classList.toggle("red") })
```

```css
button{
  background-color:green;
}
.red{
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<button>Hello World!</button>
```

Comment: Good answer! You have used `classList` which is the recommended practice.